# Modify shell variables using sed with POSIX compliance

Tags: shell, unix, sed, posix

I have this shell variable:

```
#!/bin/sh
namelist="John Doe
Josh Franklin
John Adams
"
```

To delete the lines containing "John", I use:

```
namelist=$(sed '/John/d' <<< "$namelist")
```

However, after checking for POSIX compatibility from the website called [Shellcheck,](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

it says that

```
In POSIX sh, here-strings are undefined.
```

So what would be the POSIX compliant way of modifying a variable using sed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what would be the POSIX compliant way of modifying a variable using sed?

Just don't use `<<<` and just output it to sed.

```
 namelist=$(printf "%s\n" "$namelist" | sed '/John/d')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
namelist="John Doe
Josh Franklin
John Adams
"
namelist=$(IFS=$'\n';for name in ${namelist}; do echo ${name} | grep -v "John"; done)

echo "${namelist}"
```

You can get similar output using sed aswell

```
namelist="John Doe
Josh Franklin
John Adams
"
namelist=$(IFS=$'\n';for name in ${namelist}; do echo ${name} | sed '/John/d'; done)

echo "${namelist}"
```